# Need to filter out user input to only alphanumeric, commas, fullstop and spaces

Tags: php, phpunit

I need to filter user input to only alphanumeri, commas, fullstop and spaces.
I actually tried this code below but other unwanted characters are going through.

```
if(!preg_match('/^[,. 0-9A-Za-z]/', $input)
{
   echo "invalid";
}
```

How can i enable the input to strictly accept only these characters stated above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The negation character (`^`) needs to go inside of the [character class](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php):

```
if(preg_match('/[^,\. 0-9A-Z]/i', $input))
{
   echo "invalid";
}
```

Comment: you are missing a ) .. plus the `\.` isn't needed because it isn't all chars within [] (I think)

Comment: just tried your code, its not validating at all. its just printing invalid even with alphabets only.

Comment: @Oluwafemi I tried it and it worked fine... make sure you don't put the !

Comment: the ) was included and still all to no avail!

Comment: @Oluwafemi:  What was the value of `$input`?

Comment: what do you mean craniumonempty?

Comment: There is no value, I want users to fill in those specific characters and noting else.

Comment: I mean copy the code as it is (except make sure you end the parens) and try it. It works for me. tried with `$input = "safASDFd., 09123456789asdfhgjklwqertyuiopzxcvbnmZXCVBNMASDFGHJKLQWERYUIOP";` (there is a space in there) and not invalid.. with other chars it is invalid.. What values did you test that didn't work?

Comment: just tried it and the issue is that it submits all this into mysql instead of the user input

Comment: @Oluwafemi:  Edit your original question to include the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: it goes through but with the code you stated above and not the input I type in.